# Runge-Kutta(RK4) for stiff IVP

Tags: python, differential-equations

I need a solver of stiff Inital-Value Problems (IVP) in python exploiting RK4 preferably explicit. I have been searching for past few days but could not find it. Following are my queries:

- Does the solver, i.e. any module, exist?
- If no, will it be reasonable to code one? I am asking this because I can't find any reference for using RK4-explicit for stiff problems.

Answer (score 0):

scipy seems to be able to do it (http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.ode.html) if you set the `set_integrator`to `dopri5` you get a RK4 solver

Comment: I guess it is for non-stiff problems. Does something like it exist for stiff problems?

Comment: dopri5 is what is otherwise used as ode45. It is explicit, thus unsuitable for stiff problems. On the site, no implicit solvers are mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

RK4 or the classical Runge-Kutta method is **one** specific integration method. As an explicit method, it is imminently unsuitable for stiff problems. As a one-method method, it has no intrinsic features for step size control.

For stiff problems, you want implicit RK methods with step size control.